# If the ER = EPR hypothesis is correct, could the Casimir Effect be used to allow for information transfer?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light, wormholes

[ER = EPR HYPOTHESIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER%3DEPR) 
If two entangled particles containing Einstein-Rosenberg Bridges were extremely carefully "probed" through a strong example of the Casimir Effect, could the negative density cause the "Bridges" to gain a throat; allowing information transfer? 
 
*Presumably this would not allow causality violations due to the hypothetical [Visser Effect](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9202090). (Assume the Visser Effect holds)*

*(If you are planning on downvoting this post, please give me a reason)*